# Question on labels of lists

Tags: lists

I am re-writing the Constitution of our local community center in Latex. I would like to write articles in the following format:

```
  Chapter I
1.1 First Article
1.2 Second Article

  Chapter II
2.1 First Article of Chapter 2
```

and so on.
Further I would also like to have the chapters as different subsections. Is there any method to continue the numbering into different sub-sections?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There  are may ways to do it. Will the articles have a   fixed label and no title (somewhat like ‘Article 1.1’) or no fixed label  and an title (‘1.2 *On lawn mowing*’) or both?

Comment: You might find the outlines package useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves a lot open to interpretation but something like the following shows how to have subsection numbering not restart each section. (I could not work out whether you wanted this at chapter/section level or section/subsection, but just make the obvious changes to change the affected levels)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter

\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{something}
\subsection{zzzz} zzzzzz
\subsection{bbbb} zzzzzz

\section{something else}

\subsection{zzzz again} zzzzzz
\subsection{more bbbb} zzzzzz

\end{document}
```